# How to disable specific day in ion-datetime?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I have viewed the official doc but I can't able to find out, I need a function or something like in jquery  datepicker beforeshowday function, I simply want to disabled all weekends(Saturday, Sunday) in all upcoming future dates so user can't select any date which days belongs to Saturday and Sunday
  I am using ionic v3

Comment: Please be clear about which version of ionic you are currently using

Comment: I am using ionic v3

Comment: Help me, please, i am stuck on this from last week

Comment: Please consider reading the following link which might be helpful https://github.com/HsuanXyz/ion2-calendar

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can disable a specific day with the ion-datetime component.

But you can check the  [library ion-datepicker](https://github.com/misha130/ion-datepicker)  where you can disable specific dates.

You also need to create a function that contains the weekends date you want disable.

From their documentation:

*"[disabledDates] - An array of dates that should be disabled (not required)"*

for instance in a home page:

```
    //declare it in home.ts
        public disabledDates: Date[] = [new Date(2017, 7, 14)];

        //and use it in home.html
    <span ion-datepicker  [(value)]="localDate [disabledDates]="disabledDates" clear class="ScheduleDate">
        <span>{{localDate | date}} <ion-icon name="clipboard" item-left ></ion-icon> </span>
    </span>
```

Comment: How can I use this array in my component, I mean syntax, <ion-datetime disabled=disabledDates/> is not working showing error

Comment: Hi,
I updated the library to a library you can use with recent version of Ionic (the precedent was only compatible with Ionic 1).
You can check their repo they have examples and a demo.